# Teamcity msbuild build project depend on git commit

Tags: .net, git, visual-studio-2015, teamcity

We have a problem! We need to build only the projects which have changes at git repo. But now Teamcity building solution with all projects. How can we resolve this problem?

Comment: If you can easily filter the checked out files, you can create separated TC projects for different code projects, set them all similarly but having the checkout filter modified in each one to take only the relevant files, and then TC triggers only the TC projects that are relevant to the commit.

Comment: With MSBuild, it can compare timestamps of the input files with the timestamps of the output files and determine whether to skip, build or partially rebuild a target (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171483.aspx). So, what’s the result if you build projects through MSBuild directly? If it works fine, then the issue is related to Teamcity.

Comment: In any case one of the main purposes of having a build server is making sure *everyting* builds ok after every code change, taking dependencies into account and whatnot. So trying to build only part of an antire solution seems to defeat that purpose.